# warning C4189 in concurrent_vector.h

Tags: c++, concurrency, warnings, ppl

I got following warning in my project (both Release and Debug mode):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\concurrent_vector.h(1599): warning C4189: '_Array' : local variable is initialized but not referenced
      C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\include\concurrent_vector.h(1598) : while compiling class template member function 'void Concurrency::concurrent_vector<_Ty>::_Destroy_array(void *,Concurrency::concurrent_vector<_Ty>::size_type)'
      with
      [
          _Ty=Vector3i
      ]
      d:\Some_path\somefile.h(780) : see reference to class template instantiation 'Concurrency::concurrent_vector<_Ty>' being compiled
      with
      [
          _Ty=Vector3i
      ]
```

Where somefile.h is my file and line 780 has this code:

```
Concurrency::concurrent_vector<Vector3i> m_ovColors;
```

Vector3i is something like this:

```
template<typename T> class TVector3 {
public:
    T x, y, z;
}

typedef TVector3<int>           Vector3i;
```

Code around line 1598 in concurrent_vector.h is (line 1598 is just '{'):

```
template<typename _Ty, class _Ax>
void concurrent_vector<_Ty, _Ax>::_Destroy_array( void* _Begin, size_type _N ) 
{
    _Ty* _Array = static_cast<_Ty*>(_Begin);
    for( size_type _J=_N; _J>0; --_J )
        _Array[_J-1].~_Ty(); // destructors are supposed to not throw any exceptions
}
```

What could be a reason for this?
This somefile.h when included in other projects does not issue that kind of warning.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the code turns into this because of inlining:

```
_Ty* _Array = static_cast<_Ty*>(_Begin);
for( size_type _J=_N; _J>0; --_J )
    ; // destructor has no effect!
```

At this point, the compiler stops and checks that all initialized variables are used, and emits that warning.

(The code will then be optimized to an empty function:

```
; // variable is unused
; // loop has no effect
```

but by this point the warnings have already been emitted.)

Comment: thank you, this is pretty clear.
But why it issues warning in one project and does not in other one?

Comment: @IgorTrubnikov: Different settings perhaps. If you find an answer helpful, please upvote or accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the compiler is optimizing out the loop but not the `static_cast`.  Do you have assembler/source listing for the relevant part of your program?

My experience with MSVC STL is that if you compile with `/W4` you get lots of false positives.

Answer (score 1):

This approach works:

```
#pragma warning( disable : 4189 )
#include <concurrent_vector.h>
#pragma warning( default : 4189 )
```

Thanks all

Comment: Your question wasn't about disabling warnings, it was about explaining where they were coming from. In the future, put your *actual* question in your post. We could have told you this days ago if you had asked.